# How to make polygon inside orphan of another polygon?

Tags: eaglecad

After manual routing a PCB in the Eagle CAD I widen ground net by putting a polygon on the whole PCB and naming it "GND". I disable the "orphans" options, so I have some free orphan areas on the PCB.

Now I want to use this free areas for widening the power net. For this, I create another polygon on the whole PCB with name "+5V" with greater (weaker) rank than "GND". But when I do `ratsnest`, power net are not widened, because orphans are not really free: they are in ground polygon, so power polygon can't use it.

But if I make the rank of the power and ground polygons same, both polygons connected without spacing (because Eagle can't determine boundaries between them).

How to make polygon inside orphan of another polygon with spacing?

Answer (score 3):

The rank of your +5V polygon should be **stronger than GND**.

Shape the polygon to match the +5V route. Don't create two giant polygons and expect one to magically complement the other! A small high-rank +5V polygon inside a big medium-rank GND polygon will force the GND out, regardless whether you've ticked the no-orphans option or not.

Comment: Never noticed the "rank" option before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem, you are trying to make some orphan polygons to connect them with supply. I think your approach to this problem is wrong, because Eagle logically already connect polygon at gnd net.

What you have to do is pretty simple. As I remember well you can draw the polygon any shape and any number you want. Shape polygon at area depending how your board is routed, take it a bit broader, then assign those shape to any net you want, gnd in your case. After you do same on area and create shape where you need to be your Vcc net with same principle. After *ratsnest* it should be as you ment to be.

If this answer didn't satisfy yourself, you may attach simplified brd file of problem, and I'll try to solve it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the polygone's "rank". Set the ground plane’s "rank" to 3, which means it’s less “important” and draw with the default rank of 1.

The smaller rank polygon will get drawn first and the bigger one will surround it.